# How do i fix this merged vertex and blank faces

Tags: vertices, faces, topology, retopology

I'm a newbie at blender, i followed Blender Guru's donut tutorial and I somehow messed the vertex and faces in the donut itself and the icing and cannot undo it because when i realised there's this problem, it's too late. There's 2 problem:

- The blank/missing face in the icing:
  [image: The blank/missing face in the icing]
- The merged vertex:
  [image: Merged vertex]

How do I fix this topology (if it is the right term) problem.
Thank you in advance!

Here's the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OMBtuuoT0yJypkvxGr2OglJo2k7zX5Yo/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the icing, turn on Snapping (magnet icon at the top) and select "vertex" snapping style.

[image: Snap]

Select one of the edges on the side, and extrude it with <kbd>E</kbd> until your cursor is over the vertex of the mid-point. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude again once more, and snap to the top vertex of the far side. you will see that the bottom is still not connected.

[image: Snap2]

Select the bottom vertex, press <kbd>G</kbd> to move it, and drag it over the bottom vertex on the (already exising) icing.

Snapping leaves vertices close together, but does not merge them, so select the whole mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> (in edit mode), then press <kbd>M</kbd> (merge) and select "By Distance".

[image: Merge]

For the donut, just select the two topmost vertices and join them with <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image: Join]

After this, select the diagonal edges, press <kbd>X</kbd> (delete) and select "dissolve edges".

[image: Dissolve]

**Pro Tip** - Don't forget to turn off snapping afterwards (magnet icon) - it has caused me many headaches throughout the years ;)

Comment: It works, Thank you!